# How to cancel NSOperationQueue

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsoperationqueue

Wondering if I'm implementing the below method correctly because `isCancelled` is not canceling the thread. I have an image that I'm scaling, and when it's done scaling, this method is called to update the image. So when the user lifts their finger off the button, this is called. If they try to push the button again before this is finished, I call `cancelAllOperations` on the queue but it's not working. Not even sure if cancelAllOperations triggers a flag, or if I need to keep calling it to get a result. Anyone have any insight on this?

```
- (void) refreshImage
{
    NSBlockOperation *operation = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];
    __unsafe_unretained NSBlockOperation *weakOperation = operation;

    [operation addExecutionBlock:
     ^{
         UIImage *image = [[self.graphicLayer imageForSize:self.size] retain];
         if (![weakOperation isCancelled])
         {
             [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:
              ^{
                  self.image = image;
                  [image release];
              }];
         }
         else
         {
             [image release];
             return;
         }
     }];

    [self.queue addOperation: operation];
    [operation release];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `cancelAllOperations` is called before `if (![weakOperation isCancelled])` is executed?

Comment: I really don't know to be honest LOL, one of the things I'm trying to figure out @ACB

Comment: Put NSLog statements and check which one is getting called first.

Comment: @ACB - cancelAllOperations is getting called first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, have to replace:

```
__unsafe_unretained NSBlockOperation *weakOperation = operation;
```

with:

```
__block NSBlockOperation *weakOperation = operation;
```

BTW, for anyone interested there is a good video on concurrency, in particular drawing on a separate thread and using `NSOperationQueue`'s in WWDC2012 called Building Concurrent User Interfaces on IOS.

Comment: `__block` would be appropriate, as you are mannually retain counting. See my answer to your other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484964/substituting-for-weak-when-not-using-arc/14485227#14485227

Comment: @s.bandara - Yep, saw it and I updated this response as well. Thanks!