# substituting for __weak when not using ARC

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks, nsoperationqueue, retain-cycle

I have this line of code:

```
__weak NSBlockOperation *weakOperation = operation;
```

which is triggering this compiler error:

```
__weak attribute cannot be specified on automatic variable.
```

Reason for this is I don't have ARC enabled (not ready to make the switch just yet). So from another StackOverFlow question, I was recommended to use:

```
__unsafe_unretained NSBlockOperation *weakOperation = operation;
```

Which makes the error go away, but for the context I'm using it, it's not working (see this question if interested: [How to cancel NSOperationQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432029/how-to-cancel-nsoperationqueue)).

So my question is, what I can substitute the `__weak` keyword with in this instance to get rid of this warning? Everything actually works correctly when I use `__weak`, but I'm afraid it won't hold up over future versions of iOS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not be worried about future versions of iOS because `__weak` is something interpreted by the compiler while producing code for you.

Looking at your other post suggests to me that your goal is to avoid `weakOperation` to be retained despite reference from within the block. In your specific case, where you don't use ARC, you can replace `__weak` by `__block` to indicate that your variable should *not* be retained during capture.

Note that the influence of`__block` on `retain` behavior is different between ARC and manual retain counting.